# Stopping time and filtrations

Tags: probability, measure-theory

I have a definition problem.
I know that a filtration on a probability space is an increasing sequence of $\sigma$-algebras. I was now thinking on the fact that constant times are stopping times. I've done so...

Take $T=c,$ $c\in \mathbb{Z_+}$.

Then:

$\{T=t\}=\emptyset$ for $t\neq c$

$\{T=t\}=\Omega$ for $t= c$

Now, maybe thinking wrong, I say that $\{T=t\}\in \mathcal{F_t} \forall t\geq 0$.
Since $\Omega,\emptyset\subset \mathcal{F_t}, \forall t$.
Is it right that the whole space is in all these $\sigma$-algebras?

Comment: "Since $\Omega,\emptyset\subset \mathcal{F_t}$..." Beware that $\Omega\subset \mathcal{F_t}$ is wrong, and that $\emptyset\subset \mathcal{F_t}$ is true but irrelevant. What you meant is rather that $\Omega\in\mathcal{F_t}$ and $\emptyset\in\mathcal{F_t}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By definition, $\Omega$ is in *any* $\sigma$-algebra over the given space, so yes, "the whole space" $\Omega$ is in every $\mathcal{F}_t$, because each $\mathcal{F}_t$ is a $\sigma$-algebra (by definition of "filtration").

Comment: Ah maybe now I got it... Even if I take the natural filtration, let's take $\sigma (X)$, this would contain $\Omega$ since it is the smallest $\sigma$ algebra for which X is measurable and so $X^{-1}(A)\in \sigma (X)$ $\forall A \in \mathbb{B}$. Am I right?

Comment: Yes. And note that $X^{-1}(\mathbf{R})=\Omega$, so this is another way to see that $\Omega\in\sigma(X)$. But again, $\Omega$ is in *any* $\sigma$-algebra on space $\Omega$. That's just part of the definition (or an immediate implication of the definition, at least).